# How to get bnb from contract address

Tags: solidity, cryptocurrency

I accidentally sent bnb to a tokens contract address and the Dev said he don't know how to get it out, that if I can show him how to get it out, he'll help me. So please is there a way to get my bnb from the contract address?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure this question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO but I will still answer here:

Even if the person you contacted is the owner of the contract that has been deployed, they can only withdraw the contract balance **if** they explicitly coded a specific function within the contract allowing them to do that.

Smart contracts are not accounts, they don't have private keys. They are mere code waiting to be executed by transactions or messages.

This is actually one of the major features of (most) blockchains since it allows developers to guarantee smart contract end-users that once the contract will be deployed, they won't be able to "steal" the contract balance.

Think about a lottery contract for example: the cumulated cash prize is kept on the contract balance and can only be won by the winner (and not stolen by the owner of the contract).

To check if a withdrawal function has been coded within a smart contract, you may try to:

1. Find the contract on a [blockchain explorer](https://bscscan.com)
2. Find the contract Bytecodes (a very long hexadecimal string: `6080604052600280546...`)
3. Either use the (if provided) decompiler button to check the smart contract functions or use an online solidity decompiler to do so.

Some contracts are *verified* on blockchain explorers so you can check their functions straight away from within the explorer.